# is there a place in the .info file to set a url to check for updates?

Tags: 7, theming, version-control

I created a custom theme to serve as the base for all my company's future drupal projects, that includes all of our base requirements. The sites will live on different servers, and each site will have it's own subtheme.

Drupal themes compare versions w/ the drupal projects server to check for updates.

I do not want to submit my company's theme to the drupal.org, as it has company specific features.

The goal is to be be able to update the theme in a "local" central repository, and have the various drupal sites check for version updates.

- is there a place in the .info file to set a url to check for updates?

The version number is pretty easy to set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `project status url`:

> Allows module maintainers to define a URL to check for updates to their module using the Update status module. No module released on drupal.org should define this parameter. URL should point to an XML feed that accepts requests in the form of http://my.domain.com/projects/{project}/{core}. In that example, project status url should be set to http://my.domain.com/projects.

See [Writing module .info files (Drupal 7.x)](https://drupal.org/node/542202) for full details.

Comment: There must have been like....2 seconds in this -_-

Comment: Heh, I'm getting infinity on friday, my line must be getting quicker already ;)

Answer (score 2):

Have you read the [docs](https://drupal.org/node/542202)?

> **project status url (Only used for custom modules not submitted to
>   drupal.org)**
>
> Allows module maintainers to define a URL to check for
>   updates to their module using the Update status module. No module
>   released on drupal.org should define this parameter. URL should point
>   to an XML feed that accepts requests in the form of
>   http://my.domain.com/projects/{project}/{core}. In that example,
>   project status url should be set to http://my.domain.com/projects.